# service reference call in VS2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I want to call a SAP service reference in VS2022 and I receive the error "

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
> 'Anonymous'"

also when I am trying to change the bellow code it is trying to call a HTTPS service but my service reference is HTTP. The target framework that I am using is .NET 7.0

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("");
```

In the past I was changing the settings from app.config. Instead of HTTPS I was modifying to HTTP. I want to do the same thing in VS2022 but from C# code. I also tried with different security modes but with no effect it is just switching from anonymous error to HTTPS error.

Is there any other way to define the binding and security mode?

Thank you!